# space between two spans in a link is unclickable

Tags: hyperlink, html, clickable

I have the following html code:

```
<a href="#">
 <span class="span1">test</span><span class="span2">test</span>
</a>
```

and css code:

```
.span1{float: left; }
.span2{float: right; }
```

So the link is `test  test` with about 40px space between the two words "test" and "test". I created the space simply by using css, not by `&nbsp;` or by typing space with my keyboard.

The words "test" and "test" are both click-able but the space between them is not.

How can I make the space between the two spans click-able? I have tried to wrap both of the span tags in another span tag but didn't help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the `span`s are forced into `block` display (by virtue of having given them `float` properties), you need to make sure the `a` also has `block` display and either `overflow: hidden` OR [clearfix](http://nicolasgallagher.com/micro-clearfix-hack/) such that it is certain to completely contain the space (and intervening space) occupied by its contents:

```
a {
    display: block;
    *zoom: 1;
}
a:after {
    clear: both;
    content: " ";
    display: table;
}
.span1 {
    float: left;
}
.span2 {
    float: right;
}
```

**EDIT:** based on reported weirdness in IE7:

```
*+html a * {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this works well in firefox, ie10, ie9, ie8. But in ie7 acts strangely, the link click-able, but cursor changes from pointer to text when hovered over the two words "test"s.
so I have added a span{cursor: pointer;}

Comment: @mnish weird! I'll add that to my answer just to make it complete…